# Swift UIWebView remove Edge

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, edges

As you can see in the Picture below there are edges. 
When I embed the View with a NavigationView, than the edges appears. So how can I avoid this edges??

Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ShowSubmitViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
var URL : String = ""
var type : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadBrowser()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadBrowser(){

    switch type {
    case 5:
        let htmlString:String! = URL
        webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    default:
        let url = NSURL (string: URL);
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }


 }

}
```

[Picture WebView with Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1qvo.png)

Comment: maybe post some code?

Comment: So I added the code...

Comment: What are the InterfaceBuilder settings of `webView`. If we don't know exactly how you set it up, we can't help you :/

Comment: It's all the standard. It happend when I embed the view in the Navigation Controll... In the same project I made a View without navigation  controll and it dont happend

Comment: As I thought, it is an IB setting. Next time please listen and provide all info so that others don't have to put in time setting up projects to replicate. Go to IB, select your ViewController, go to the Attributes Inspector and deselect "Under Top Bars"

Comment: Did that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. :)